# CSS Marquee Slider Compensate Outer Width Minus Inner Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

So I have a marquee slider that takes a bunch of images, scrolls them to the left, and when the first image hits the left of the page, it comes back from the right side again infinitely.

My issue is that there is a gap between the last image, and the first image that comes again. I believe the theory to fix this is by using jQuery to calculate the sum of all of the images in the first `<span>`, subtract that from what the width of the container is, and then adding a negative `margin-left` with that differential number. I have tried the following code, but the issue is that I am not familiar enough with jQuery to pull the widths. Also, I need a solution that will calculate the new container width on window resize (since the container is set to 100% and will certainly change).

NOTE: The two spans contain THE SAME EXACT IMAGES. The reason for this is for the second span to scroll into view as soon as the first one hits the far left.  This loops infinitely.

```
<script>

var marqueeWidth = $('.marquee div span').innerWidth();

var marqueeWidth2 = 0;
$('.marquee div span img').each(function(){
    marqueeWidth2  += $(this).innerWidth();
});

console.log(marqueeWidth / 2);
console.log(marqueeWidth2);

</script>
```

> Full Code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hybridx24/5nuxfed5/2/

Comment: Do you need to keep the html structure in the jsfiddle, or can we change it?

Comment: Feel free to change it, although I believe most of the issue is jQuery related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/5nuxfed5/11/

I've made some changes to the html, the 2 span are now div.flex_container, which are inline-flex elements with 100% width.

```
.flex_container {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Also I prevented the images to wrap to the next line with `white-space: nowrap`

```
.marquee {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;  /* Inline-block spacing issue hack */
  animation: marquee 5s infinite linear;
}
```

Inside each flex box the images are rescaled within its own container, fitting the entire screen width while keeping its ratio:

```
.marquee img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Edit: added an outer wrapper to remove scroll bar, and added a flex-grow to grow the img if there's free space.

Comment: Awesome! I ended up modifying this code a bit so that the height is fixed at 200px for each image. My issue now is that if the first element has a different width than any other element, there is an overlap (this is a real scenario). Here is a JSFiddle recreating the issue (look at the `imgTEST` overlapping a box. http://jsfiddle.net/Hybridx24/jLkxaw0u/

Comment: 1. sum of all image width = screen size 2. all images height = 200px 3. image ratio stay the same. Please choose only 2 among those, you can't satisfy all 3. Your "bug" is because the fixed height is breaking rule #1 and pushing the images longer than screen width.

Comment: If you want your images to have the same displayed height, simply provide images with the same height and they will automagically line up with each other into a horizontal row. If you want fixed 200px though, I can't think of a way to do it (not even with js, if you think about it)

Answer (score 0):

I have made a slider using jquery, which is little bit different from your query. But I hope it may fulfill your reqirement.

URL: http://demos4clients.com/mygallery/

You need to include jquery library file and image into the slider. Also you can change time duration in jquery code.